# Python is giving the error message as seen below, i do not know what it means

Tags: python

Python isnt executing,

the error message:

```
Program 'python3.11.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the path specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ & C:/Users/stijn/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ & C:/Users/stijn/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

My code:

```
import random

times = 0

passcode = input("What is the password you are trying to encode?:\n")

while times < 10:
    times += 1
    encotion = random.randint(1,99)
    print(encotion)
```

I have tried reinstalling python and doing it through pip

Comment: Just a guess, should the executable name be `python311.exe` instead of `python3.11.exe`?

Comment: Also, that error message is from powershell, not from python.

Answer (score 0):

```
Program 'python3.11.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the path specifiedAt line:1 char:1
```

the system has failed to find the python interpreter meaning you might have to reinstall it